# how to defineProperty navigator to be undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, jsdom

I am trying to test for the navigator object with Jest:

in Node.js 10.8 this works:

```
it('should test if navigator is undefined', () => {
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'navigator', { value: undefined, writable: true });
    const getOs = Helpers.getMobileOS();
    expect(getOs).toEqual(false);
});
```

in Node.js 8.6 it doesn't work.

Comment: you can use window only in  web-browser

Comment: i'm using Jest, so it is using JSDOM

Comment: see this - https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3692#issuecomment-408132529

Comment: thanks - I tried using global it still doesn't work.